# How do you process the process id of a fork in a node.js application?

Tags: node.js

I want to log the process id of a fork when I log an action, but I am not sure how to access the variable where it's held.

I couldn't find if the process id is held inside a global variable and also identify which one is running when the express routes are being executed, so I am in a kind of a bind here.

```
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
        res.json(user);
        customLogger.log(`action A performed by process ${}`);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
});
```

I just want to get something like: "action A performed by process J85T".

Comment: Are you running your server as a cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there in the `process` object: `process.pid`.